# Detect 360 degree video youtube support

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube, 360-degrees

What is the best solution to detect if browser supports 360 degree video from youtube (via JS)?
Youtube support team says [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6178631?hl=en).
Can someone provide code like below

```
    if(video360supported) {
    // my code
    } else {...}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there is currently.  According to Google, it is something that they are working on exposing to Javascript from their Chrome browser. (https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7547&q=reporter%3Asmartsystemdesign&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

Comment: In this case how to init variable var video360supported?

Answer (score -1):

The code above should work fine, for example:

```
if(video360support) {
#play video
}else
     print('Sorry your browser doesn't support the video type')
```

Or something along those lines.